# Adding dll version number to log4net PatternLayout

Tags: c#, log4net, paas

We are using a custom pattern in log4net with great success but I cant seem to work out how to get the dll version number of dll from which the exception was thrown. Any ideas?

https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html

We run multiple different client sites on different versions so knowing the version number of the dll which generated the exception would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to get the dll version at logging time:

```
…
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var version = GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();
    ThreadContext.Properties["version"] = version;
    log.Error(ex);
}
```

Then in your PatternLayout, reference `%property{version}` to retrieve the value.